# Overwrite Foundation table background color single row with Angular

Tags: css, angularjs, zurb-foundation

In a list of users I want to highlight a particular row that matches a user's current rank. 
My problem is that with `ng-class` it doesn't seem to override the Foundation `background-color` for that row even when the conditional expression matches. The row looks like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in displayUsers" ng-class="{'userSelectedBackground': user.rank == regularRank}">
```

I output `user.rank == regularRank` just to test it and I do get back true on the row I want to highlight. Developer tools show that my `userSelectedBackground` class is being applied, but I can't see where it's being overwritten. I've also tried attaching an !important tag even, with no success:

```
.userSelectedBackground {
    background-color: #4C4CFF !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foundation's `:nth-of-type(even)` rule is taking precedence over your class styling. You need to target it more specifically:

```
.userSelectedBackground,
.userSelectedBackground:nth-of-type(even),
.userSelectedBackground:nth-of-type(odd){
  background-color:red;
}
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/zz3e0q5s/).

Comment: Thanks, after getting more specific targeting it worked fine!